# Openfire server configuration on AWS ubuntu 18.04 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, openfire

How to configure openfire server on AWS properly? I have installed openfire on aws and run, show admin console and server setting is completed.

When i create new user show the following error:

> Exception:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
>       at org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.DefaultAuthProvider.setPassword(DefaultAuthProvider.java:323)
>       at org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthFactory.setPassword(AuthFactory.java:183)
>       at org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.DefaultUserProvider.createUser(DefaultUserProvider.java:167)
>       at org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.UserManager.createUser(UserManager.java:214)
>       at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.user_002dcreate_jsp._jspService(user_002dcreate_jsp.java:161)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
>       at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
>       at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>       at org.jivesoftware.util.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:73)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>       at org.jivesoftware.util.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:49)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>       at org.jivesoftware.admin.PluginFilter.doFilter(PluginFilter.java:226)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>       at org.jivesoftware.admin.AuthCheckFilter.doFilter(AuthCheckFilter.java:215)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

When i access the openfire using Spark show error connection refuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not a lot of details in your question that would help someone identify the problem, for instance, what OS, which version of Openfire and what version of Java you're using.

Openfire versions up to the most recent at the time I'm writing this (v4.3.0) are incompatible with Java 9 and up. That's a common source of problems. Try downgrading to Java 8.

Comment: I'm using Linux operation system ubuntu 18.04, openfire 4.2.3 and using  java-8-oracle

Comment: The error suggests that you're running with Java 9 or later. My advice is to double-check what version is used to run Openfire. Be aware that it is perfectly normal to have more than one version of Java installed on your system. Even if you installed Java 8, another version might be used.

Comment: Openfire version is 4.3.0 and java version


/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java ,         /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java,       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java , 
     /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java

Comment: I'm guessing that Openfire is usuing on of the Java 11 instances, instead of Java 8.If you're not using it for anything else, maybe you can remove Java 11 completely. You'll otherwise have to set JAVA_HOME or modify the start scripts for Openfire, to use Java 8.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Guus. My problem is solved . Remove java 11 and install java 8.

Comment: Maybe mark this as the correct answer then, to let others know. :)